# Getting count of elements in multidimensional array and specifying a filter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, filtering

I want to get the count of `country` records in a multidimensional array.
I also would like to get the same count, but filtered by the record, so `count` of `the Netherlands`.

I've tried this:

```
$total = array_sum(array_map("count", $data));
echo "total: " . $total;
```

It counts the number of records in the array.

I've tried:

```
$element = 'institutionID';
$count = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'institutionID'))[$element];
echo $count;
```

But nothing is returned. How do I do this?

data example

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [higherGeographyID] => http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/7016845
            [higherGeography] => None
            [continent] => Europe
            [waterBody] => None
            [islandGroup] => None
            [island] => None
            [country] => The Netherlands
            [countryCode] => NL
            [stateProvince] => Groningen
            [county] => Groningen
            [municipality] => Groningen
            [locality] => Groningen
            [verbatimLocality] => None
            [minimumElevationInMeters] => None
            [maximumElevationInMeters] => None
            [verbatimElevation] => None
            [minimumDepthInMeters] => None
            [maximumDepthInMeters] => None
            [verbatimDepth] => None
            [minimumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters] => None
            [maximumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters] => None
            [locationAccordingTo] => None
            [locationRemarks] => None
            [decimalLatitude] => None
            [decimalLongitude] => None
            [geodeticDatum] => None
            [coordinateUncertaintyInMeters] => None
            [coordinatePrecision] => None
            [pointRadiusSpatialFit] => None
            [verbatimCoordinates] => None
            [verbatimLatitude] => None
            [verbatimLongitude] => None
            [verbatimCoordinateSystem] => None
            [verbatimSRS] => None
            [footprintWKT] => None
            [footprintSRS] => None
            [footprintSpatialFit] => None
            [georeferencedBy] => None
            [georeferencedDate] => None
            [georeferenceProtocol] => None
            [georeferenceSources] => None
            [georeferenceVerificationStatus] => None
            [georeferenceRemarks] => None
          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ...
```

Comment: You want to count the number of occurrences of the `country` key, no matter how deep?

Comment: If you could revise your "data example" to include some white-space hierarchy would be helpful, indentation

Comment: @GetSet yes, no matter how deep, although it will always be at this level.

Comment: @GetSet white space added to make the same data more human readable.

Comment: Ok. How is `country` delimited? That is, what "data structure" or "format" do you have for `country`? Can it be more than one value in that field? It might seem like a filler question but am wondering why you just don't loop through and increment a `cnt` var when that array key exists?

Comment: Is *every* entry in `$data` the same as the one you have posted?

Comment: @Nick The data above is the result of `print("<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre>");`

Comment: @GetSet the `Country` element only expects one term/value per object/array. The accepted answer does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count of `country` records:

```
$dataCountry = array_column($data, 'country');
echo "total: ", count($dataCountry);
```

Count of `The Netherlands`:

```
$dataCountryCount = array_count_values(array_filter($dataCountry));
echo $dataCountryCount['The Netherlands'] ?? 0;
```

Multiple search filter:

```
$filter = ['country' => 'The Netherlands', 'continent' => 'Europe'];
$dataFilter = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($filter) {
    return $filter == array_intersect_key($item, $filter);
});
echo 'total:', count($dataFilter);

print_r($dataFilter);
```

Comment: This would only count correctly if 'country' is one the first level of the array and I don't think that is what OP expected.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld and yet it seems to work... I'll do some manual calculations to check its behaviour... any way to add in a second filter like `continent['Europe']`? I'm still getting my head around php after returning from python (django).

Comment: @SpatialDigger, added an example of multiple search filter.

Comment: @SpatialDigger - yes it would work based on your example but if you another level down (with country) in your arrays it would not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:

```
  $data = json_decode($data_json,true);

  echo count_filtered_by($data);
  // Returns (int) 3
  echo count_filtered_by($data,'country');
  // Returns (int) 3
  echo count_filtered_by($data,'country','The Netherlands');
  // Retruns (int) 2
  echo count_filtered_by($data,'country','UK');
  // Returns (int) 1
  echo count_filtered_by($data,'country','uK',true);
  // Returns (int) 0

  /**
  * Count filtered by
  * 
  * @param array $data
  * @param string|nullable $key
  * @param string|nullable $value
  * @param bool $strict Default is (Case Insensitive)
  * 
  * @return int count filtered by
  */
  function count_filtered_by($data,$key = NULL,$value = NULL,$strict = false) {
    $column = array_column($data,$key);
    if($key === NULL) return count($data);
    if($value === NULL ) return count($column);
    // Remove empty values
    $filtered = array_filter($column);

    $count = 0;
    foreach($filtered as $column) {
      if(!$strict) {
        $column = strtolower($column);
        $value = strtolower($value);
      }
      if($column === $value) $count++;
    }

    return $count;
  }
```

So I test your data here

```
  $data_json = '[
      {
          "higherGeographyID": "http:\/\/vocab.getty.edu\/tgn\/7016845",
          "higherGeography": "None",
          "continent": "Europe",
          "waterBody": "None",
          "islandGroup": "None",
          "island": "None",
          "country": "The Netherlands",
          "countryCode": "NL",
          "stateProvince": "Groningen",
          "county": "Groningen",
          "municipality": "Groningen",
          "locality": "Groningen",
          "verbatimLocality": "None",
          "minimumElevationInMeters": "None",
          "maximumElevationInMeters": "None",
          "verbatimElevation": "None",
          "minimumDepthInMeters": "None",
          "maximumDepthInMeters": "None",
          "verbatimDepth": "None",
          "minimumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters": "None",
          "maximumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters": "None",
          "locationAccordingTo": "None",
          "locationRemarks": "None",
          "decimalLatitude": "None",
          "decimalLongitude": "None",
          "geodeticDatum": "None",
          "coordinateUncertaintyInMeters": "None",
          "coordinatePrecision": "None",
          "pointRadiusSpatialFit": "None",
          "verbatimCoordinates": "None",
          "verbatimLatitude": "None",
          "verbatimLongitude": "None",
          "verbatimCoordinateSystem": "None",
          "verbatimSRS": "None",
          "footprintWKT": "None",
          "footprintSRS": "None",
          "footprintSpatialFit": "None",
          "georeferencedBy": "None",
          "georeferencedDate": "None",
          "georeferenceProtocol": "None",
          "georeferenceSources": "None",
          "georeferenceVerificationStatus": "None"
      },
      {
          "higherGeographyID": "http:\/\/vocab.getty.edu\/tgn\/7016845",
          "higherGeography": "None",
          "continent": "Europe",
          "waterBody": "None",
          "islandGroup": "None",
          "island": "None",
          "country": "The Netherlands",
          "countryCode": "NL",
          "stateProvince": "Groningen",
          "county": "Groningen",
          "municipality": "Groningen",
          "locality": "Groningen",
          "verbatimLocality": "None",
          "minimumElevationInMeters": "None",
          "maximumElevationInMeters": "None",
          "verbatimElevation": "None",
          "minimumDepthInMeters": "None",
          "maximumDepthInMeters": "None",
          "verbatimDepth": "None",
          "minimumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters": "None",
          "maximumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters": "None",
          "locationAccordingTo": "None",
          "locationRemarks": "None",
          "decimalLatitude": "None",
          "decimalLongitude": "None",
          "geodeticDatum": "None",
          "coordinateUncertaintyInMeters": "None",
          "coordinatePrecision": "None",
          "pointRadiusSpatialFit": "None",
          "verbatimCoordinates": "None",
          "verbatimLatitude": "None",
          "verbatimLongitude": "None",
          "verbatimCoordinateSystem": "None",
          "verbatimSRS": "None",
          "footprintWKT": "None",
          "footprintSRS": "None",
          "footprintSpatialFit": "None",
          "georeferencedBy": "None",
          "georeferencedDate": "None",
          "georeferenceProtocol": "None",
          "georeferenceSources": "None",
          "georeferenceVerificationStatus": "None"
      },
      {
          "higherGeographyID": "http:\/\/vocab.getty.edu\/tgn\/7016845",
          "higherGeography": "None",
          "continent": "Europe",
          "waterBody": "None",
          "islandGroup": "None",
          "island": "None",
          "country": "UK",
          "countryCode": "UK",
          "stateProvince": "Groningen",
          "county": "Groningen",
          "municipality": "Groningen",
          "locality": "Groningen",
          "verbatimLocality": "None",
          "minimumElevationInMeters": "None",
          "maximumElevationInMeters": "None",
          "verbatimElevation": "None",
          "minimumDepthInMeters": "None",
          "maximumDepthInMeters": "None",
          "verbatimDepth": "None",
          "minimumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters": "None",
          "maximumDistanceAboveSurfaceInMeters": "None",
          "locationAccordingTo": "None",
          "locationRemarks": "None",
          "decimalLatitude": "None",
          "decimalLongitude": "None",
          "geodeticDatum": "None",
          "coordinateUncertaintyInMeters": "None",
          "coordinatePrecision": "None",
          "pointRadiusSpatialFit": "None",
          "verbatimCoordinates": "None",
          "verbatimLatitude": "None",
          "verbatimLongitude": "None",
          "verbatimCoordinateSystem": "None",
          "verbatimSRS": "None",
          "footprintWKT": "None",
          "footprintSRS": "None",
          "footprintSpatialFit": "None",
          "georeferencedBy": "None",
          "georeferencedDate": "None",
          "georeferenceProtocol": "None",
          "georeferenceSources": "None",
          "georeferenceVerificationStatus": "None"
      }
  ]';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could do this:

```
//Example data for testing
$arr = [
    ['a'=> ['country' => 'Netherland']],
    ['e'=> ['country' => 'Netherland']],
    ['b'=> ['country' => 'Sweden']],
    ['c'=> ['country' => 'Netherland'], 'a' => ['country' => 'Netherland']],
    ['f'=> ['country' => 'Sweden']],
];

//Init som global variables 
$count_countries = 0; //Number of occurences of 'country'
$check_country = 'Netherland'; //What country to check
$count_country = 0; //Number of occurences for chosen country to check

//Walk through array recursively and count each found occurence of 
//country and the actual country to check
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item, $key) {
    global $count_countries, $count_country, $check_country;
    if ($key == 'country') $count_countries++;
    if ($item == $check_country) $count_country++;
});

//Output result
echo 'count for ' . $check_country . ' = ' . $count_country . '<br>';
echo 'count for countries = ' . $count_countries;
```

**Result in this case:**

```
count for Netherland = 4
count for countries = 6
```